# Does this site need more moderators?

Tags: discussion, meta, stackapps, moderation-request

I've noticed that flags that I have raised on Stack Apps stopped being handled late last year. According to our [moderators page](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=moderators), we have two moderators, but looking at profiles indicates that one hasn't been seen since April 2019, and the other hasn't been on in over a week.

Do we need additional moderators on this site? If so, should we ask Stack Exchange for appointments or should we have full elections? When should this happen?

Answer (score 6):

Users [Glorfindel](https://stackapps.com/users/34061/glorfindel) and [rene](https://stackapps.com/users/18722/rene) were [appointed](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=moderators) as [moderators](https://stackapps.com/election/) on [June 2 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgvTQ.png), they join [Tim Stone](https://stackapps.com/users/4746/tim-stone). Currently one is a moderator on a few sites and both are active on the Stack Exchange network, usually a few times per day; we might expect that flag handling times will improve from "[days](https://stackapps.com/a/8574/58236)" to hours.

Answer (score 2):

Flags here are being acted upon, it is just that sometimes they take a couple of days to be seen.  No moderator on any site is expected to be active every day.

There are a number of the lower-traffic sites here in a similar position.  That is, keeping going with only one or two moderators.  I'm sure The Powers That Be are aware of this and will be appointing / electing new moderators in due course.  After all, there are moderator elections in progress on four sites at this moment.

The moderator(s) that we have can ask directly for assistance or additional moderators.  Your question has raised the issue, we could wait a while to see if there is a response.